# What is the difference between refl and rfl in Lean 3?

Tags: lean, beginner, lean3, equality

I already know that `refl` is called a tactic, and that `rfl` is a term; can you explain with examples how they technically differ? I've read that `refl` is "more powerful", but I never knew beforehand if one would definitely work where the other may not. Bonus points for `by exact rfl` explanations. I also wonder if there are significant changes to these between different versions of Lean 3...

Comment: I changed the `reflexivity` tag to `equality`. Presumably there is no point in splitting `equality` into `reflexivity`, `symmetry`, `transitivity`, etc.

Comment: I can't seem to edit it. I can only edit some tags but not others. Or maybe I don't know how to use the internet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you are correct that `refl` is a tactic, and `rfl` is a term, so for example:

```
example : 1 = 1 := rfl
example : nat = nat := by refl -- equivalent to putting `rfl`
```

But `refl` is more powerful, as it can also apply other lemmas that have the `@[refl]` attribute on them (like `rfl`) :

```
example : true ↔ true := rfl -- error!
example : true ↔ true := by refl -- fine! makes term `iff.rfl`
example : 0 ≤ 0 := by refl -- fine!
```

There are other similar tactics for `symmetry` (also `symmetry'` which is slightly better) and `transitivity`, both with their related attributes.

`by exact rfl` is a hack used to deal with the elaborator, which sometimes can infer what you mean wrong, but putting it into a tactic state forces it to realise what's going on. A similar hack is `show _, from ...` (although it seems this isn't commonly used with `rfl`)

Comment: In the first line, `rfl` and `refl` seem like they should be swapped

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `refl` is able to prove equalities because `eq.refl` has the `[refl]` attribute (i.e., equality isn't a special case). It's also part of a suite of three tactics for applying lemmas for relations: `refl`, `symmetry`, and `transitivity`.

Answer (score 9):

Separately from the `rfl` (term) vs `refl` (tactic) distinction, there is also the distinction between `rfl` and `refl` in lemma names:

```
#check @eq.refl  -- ∀ {α : Sort u_2} (a : α), a = a
#check @rfl      -- ∀ {α : Sort u_2} {a : α}, a = a

#check @iff.refl -- ∀ (a : Prop), a ↔ a
#check @iff.rfl  -- ∀ {a : Prop}, a ↔ a

#check @le_refl  -- ∀ {α : Type u_2} [_inst_1 : preorder α] (a : α), a ≤ a
#check @le_rfl   -- ∀ {α : Type u_2} [_inst_1 : preorder α] {a : α}, a ≤ a
```

The difference here is that that `rfl` uses an implicit `{}` binder for `a`, while `refl` uses a explicit `()` binder. So `iff.rfl` is shorthand for `iff.refl _`, `le_rfl` is shorthand for `le_refl _`, etc.